# How to Fill dataGridView in C# by SqlCeCommand

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database file (`.sdf`) in C#; with the code I can read from `albums_tbl` but I want to create a row for every record of table while by clicking on a specific row I will be able to get its name and id.

`albums_tbl` table has two columns: `id, name`

```
SqlCeDataReader rdr = null;
SqlCeCommand cm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM albums_tbl  ", cn);

rdr = cm.ExecuteReader();

int n =  0;

while (rdr.Read())
{
    // rdr.GetString(0) is id
    // rdr.GetString(1) is name
    label1.Text =  rdr.GetString(1) ;
}
```

I did this when I used sql conncetion  :

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM album_items WHERE name LIKE N'%" + searchItemName.Text + "%'  ", con);
searchItemName.Text = ""; 

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();

foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    int n = dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["id"].ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["name"].ToString();
}
```

and after that I could get information by clicking on any row by this code :

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        albumId.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        albumName.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I want to do it now using a `SqlCeCommand`